# Requesting to API doesn't work in the server but works in the browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, request

as I mentioned in the title, I have an API, which provides me with detailed information about countries. I have created an express server which handles API requests. Problem is that it doesn't make a request, but the same URL returns JSON when requesting from browser URL. On the other hand, I have tried another API which returns me an answer. So I am confused about this situation. I need responses from that API.
Here is my server code `

```
const express = require('express');
const request = require('request');

const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

const app = express();

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

let country = '';

request({
  url: `https:restcountries.eu/rest/v2/name/${country}?fullText=true`,
  json: true
}, (error, response, body) => {
  console.log('ddfd');
  if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
    console.log(body, 'body');
  }
});

app.get('/countries', (req, res) => {
  country = req.query.name;
  console.log(country, 'country');
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is up on port ${port}`);
});
```

Comment: do you controlled with ctrl F5 keywords?

Comment: Why do i need it ?

Comment: Clear browser cache

Comment: it doesn't work because of this `let country = ''` ...you have not specified a country for which data you want. `${country}` in your url is then empty string..is that how the api works? you should move the request into the `/countries` route to get the country and insert it correctly. outside of the route it won't work

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Why are'nt you invoking the request inside your api?

```
app.get('/countries', (req, res) => {
  country = req.query.name;
  console.log(country, 'country');
  request({
    url: `https:restcountries.eu/rest/v2/name/${country}?fullText=true`,
    json: true
  }, (error, response, body) => {
    if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
      console.log(body, 'body');
      res.send(body);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: **https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all** only this api works , but it returns ALL countries and this is not efficient

Comment: **https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/name/united**  this link also works from the API website examples , but its strange , even my input is `united` , it's not going to return anything . May be some parsing error coming from input ?